# Maximo 7.6 - Adding 'Change Status' icon to tool bar in Work Order Tracking

Tags: maximo

We are trying to add the 'change status' icon (in Maximo 7.6) on the toolbar (up top) in the Work Order Tracking application. We already have it in the 'Actions' menu to the left. But, some of our field workers, who work on smaller screens (laptops), like to minimize the navigation bar to give the page more room. We know about the keyboard shortcut for change status, but I'd still like to know if anyone else is having this issue and how it was fixed.

It seems like it would be easy enough. We go into Application Designer, bring up the 'Work Order Tracking' application, select 'Status' and make sure that it is checked as 'visible.' But, it never shows. (see second screen shot)

We also tried editing the XML but were unsuccessful there also. Seems as if IBM left code for 'Change Status', for Work Order Tracking, out of the upgrade from 7.5 to 7.6. (because we know this is not a problem in 7.5)

Have any of you seen this issue and what can be done to fix this?

Thanks. -Ryan

### [image: Screen shot from Work Order Tracking in Application Designer]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

IBM posted this solution. Wish I would have seen this earlier. Toolbar icons are added globally in system properties. Configured in the applications.

[IBM Support - Adding Icons to Toolbars ... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641394](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641394)